# Substring help in batch file

Tags: batch-file

How do I extract everything between incno and the space ie12345678 in the example batch below and put it into a incno variable?

```
@echo off  
Set mystring=test incno12345678 wo5555 locFred Street   
Echo "my string=%mystring%"   
Echo incno   
Echo wo    
Echo loc
```

The incno can be 8 to 11 digits long but will always be between incno and a space in the string

I am now having trouble assigning the %%d variable to the mystring variable now it is in a for loop. Can anyone help me with this? See Below.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
color 0B
For /d %%d in ("C:\Users\%Username%\LocalData\*") do (
Echo "Folder = %%d"
Set mystring=%%d
echo "MyString = %mystring%"
pause
REM delete until (including) "incno":
set mystring=%mystring:*incno=%
echo %mystring%
REM delete starting with (including) " ":
set mystring=%mystring: =&rem %
echo "Incident Number = %mystring%"
pause
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "mystring=test incno12345678 wo5555 locFred Street"
for /f %%V in ("%mystring:* incno=%") do set "incno=%%V"
```

Delayed expansion can be used if there is a chance that mystring might contain poison characters plus quotes:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set mystring=test incno12345678 wo5555 loc"4th & Main"
for /f %%V in ("!mystring:* incno=!") do set "incno=%%V"
```

If the resultant value might contain `!` (not an issue in this case) then delayed expansion must be toggled

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set mystring=test varABC!XYZ "&)^|<>"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%V in ("!mystring:* var=!") do (
  endlocal
  set "var=%%V"
)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with substring replacement in two steps:

```
Set mystring=test incno12345678 wo5555 locFred Street
echo %mystring%
REM delete until (including) "incno":
set mystring=%mystring:*incno=%
echo %mystring%
REM delete starting with (including) " ":
set mystring=%mystring: =&rem %
echo %mystring%
```

Comment: How does `set mystring=%mystring: =&rem %` work? I can't find that documented anywhere? What does the `&rem ` do?

Comment: @DavidPostill - Do the replacement on paper and you will see. It simply inserts a concatenated REM command, so the rest of the string is ignored.

Comment: The only problem with this technique is it is not immune to issues with a mixture of poison characters and quotes, nor can it be modified to be so.

Comment: @sambul35 ss64 is always my first point of reference, and I know (in general) how to use string replacement (which is evident if you look at my answers on [su]). However, it does not describe that particular trick (which is new to me) and is obvious when it is pointed out by the master :)

Comment: @DavidPostill: you may review more examples of this trick at [this thread](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429).

Comment: @Stephan can you help me with getting your solution to work in a for loop? See modified question above

Comment: just use [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)